# Make link target depend on form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a django view which contains a simple form and a table of links.  The form has a dropdown box, and the link's query parameters should contain the value of the dropdown.  So for example if the dropdown has options 1, 2 and 3, and 2 is selected, the link targets in the top three rows of the table should be something like this:

```
/preview/first?other_arg=somevalue&choice=2
/preview/second?different=argument&choice=2
/preview/third?choice=2
```

Everything except the `arg=2` is predefined for each row.

It seems to me that there are two ways of doing this.  Either I could recreate all the links whenever the dropdown value changes, or I could create the link when it is clicked.  I've been trying to do it via the second method, but I can't get it to work (i.e. nothing happens when I click on the link).  I created a fiddle showing my test code:
http://jsfiddle.net/LcY8c/4/

Is this the best approach, and can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed you fiddle a bit. Changed the id's to class, and the jQuery from an click event to a change event. Is it this you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/Grevling/LcY8c/17/

```
<div>
<select id="choiced">
    <option choice="1">1</option>
    <option choice="2">2</option>
    <option choice="3">3</option>
</select>
</div>
<div>

<a class="link" base="/link1" href="#">link1</a>
<a class="link" base="/link2?arg1=1" href="#">link2</a>
<a class="link" base="/link3?arg1=other" href="#">link3</a>

</div>
```

Script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#choiced").change(function () {
        var reportType = $('#choiced').val();
        var link = $('a').attr('base') + '&choice=' + reportType;


        $("a").each(function (index) { 
            $(this).attr("base", $(this).attr("base") + '&choice=' + reportType);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Not quite - I only want the popup to open when the link is clicked, which I suppose means somehow connecting the function to a class instead of an id?

Comment: I updated the code to add the value to the link instead, hope it's what you're looking for now :)

Comment: Different approach, but it does what I want!  Only thing to change is that it should write it to `href`, not `base`, and I need it to initialise with a valid link (i.e. not `#`), but I should be able to work the rest out.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an id attribute with the same value 3 times. Id attributes are supposed to be unique.

```
<a id="link" base="/link1" href="#">link1</a>
<a id="link" base="/link2?arg1=1" href="#">link2</a>
<a id="link" base="/link3?arg1=other" href="#">link3</a>
```

Comment: Thanks - kinda obvious now that you mention it, but I didn't know that!